# How to color text a li tag of the ul tag by Javascript or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm new at Javascript. I have the following code html:

```
<body>
    <ul id="a" class="list1">
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="b" class="list2">
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
  </ul>
  <script type="text/javascript">      
  </script>
</body>
```

How to color the text for each last li tag in the ul tags below? I was thinking of setting id for each li tag then using getElementById() method but that is quite wordy. Is there any other way without changing the structure of the html code? Can use Jquery but I don't know much about it.

Thanks for your help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnNTm.png)

Comment: you don't need javascript to get that done. just use CSS. as Asutosh has mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead,

Get last child (li) of every li `document.querySelectorAll("ul li:last-child")`

```js
var secondli = document.querySelectorAll("ul li:last-child");
for(i=0;i<secondli.length;i++){
  var li = secondli[i];
  li.style.color = "red";
}
```

```html
<body>
    <ul id="a" class="list1">
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="b" class="list2">
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
  </ul>
  <script type="text/javascript">      
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: How wonderful, using for loop is easy to understand. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```html
<style>
li:last-child{
color:red;
}
</style>
<body>
    <ul id="a" class="list1">
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li class="liColorChanger">Tea</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="b" class="list2">
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li class="liColorChanger">Tea</li>
  </ul>
  <script type="text/javascript">      
  </script>
</body>
```

```html
<style>
    .liColorChanger
    {
    color:green;
        }
</style>
<body>
    <ul id="a" class="list1">
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li class="liColorChanger">Tea</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="b" class="list2">
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li class="liColorChanger">Tea</li>
  </ul>
  <script type="text/javascript">      
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that through CSS, using :last-child

```css
li:last-child{
color:red;
}
```

```html
    <ul id="a" class="list1">
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="b" class="list2">
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
  </ul>
```

in js also you can achive it like below:

```
window.addEventListener('load',()=>{
document.querySelectorAll('li:last-child').forEach((elem)=>{elem.style.color='red'});
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I have used it already. I want to try something else like Javascript.

Comment: @BìnhDương Added the JS way also now.

Answer (score 0):

use element selector and last child selector:

it selects all the last li in ul: find the below example

`ul > li:last-child{ color:red; }`

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please have a look you don't need to repeat loop it's just simple you can add css.

Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var listA = document.querySelector("#a li:last-child");
  var listB = document.querySelector("#b li:last-child");
  listA.style.color = "red"
  listB.style.color = "red"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated by everyone - you do not need javascript or jquery for this - but in the name of learning - here is a jquery way

Iterate over each of the uls - find the li's within and select the last one... then add a class - and the styling is on the class. It isalways better to add a class with styling - rather than using jquery to add css directly.

But as noted - I would definitely usee CSS only - and use the :last-child pseudo-selector as described by other solutions.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul').each(function(){
    $(this).find('li').last().addClass('red');
  })
})
```

```css
.red{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="a" class="list1">
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="b" class="list2">
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Of course as you said, using CSS is always the best and simplest way